# How to catch internal TensorFlow error: 'GPU sync failed' in python?

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu

TensorFlow versions: 1.x and 2.x.

Is a way to catch an error with try-expect in python?

`tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError: GPU sync failed`

How to check is '**e**' a '**GPU sync failed**' error without comparing string?

```
try:
   #do_something

except InternalError as e:
   if is_e_the_gpu_sync_failed(e):
      #do something
```

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/45901